# How to fill out login form with mechanize in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, forms, screen-scraping, mechanize

Below the form that I wish to fill with Mechanize; already tried the model commonly used (example there: [Using Ruby and Mechanize to fill in a remote login form mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955267/using-ruby-and-mechanize-to-fill-in-a-remote-login-form-mystery)); but didn't succeed.

```
<form method="post" action="/sso/login.php" id="form-login-page">
  <div id="form-login-container-page" style="color:red;text-align:center;width:100%;margin:10px 0"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="minimalist" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="SSO_Context" value="/pdf/telecharger2.php?pdfpf=&amp;pdfg=%2Fpdf%2Ftelecharger.php%3Fdir%3DJOURNAL%26file%3D20140603.pdf">
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">
    <input class="insc-saisie-champ" type="text" id="login-page" name="login" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label>Mot de passe<span>*</span></label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">
    <input class="insc-saisie-champ" type="password" id="password-page" name="password"  value="">
  </div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" unchecked=""></label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">Se souvenir</div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">
    <a href="javascript:showLostPassForm();">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">
    <input class="b-connexion" type="image" src="/img/trans.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <label><span>*</span></label>
  <div class="insc-saisie">Saisie obligatoire</div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</form>
```

Here my attempt

```
form = agent.page.parser.css('form')[1]
agent.page.forms[1]["login"] = "my_login" 
agent.page.forms[1]["password"] = "my_password"
agent.page.forms[1].submit
```

Comment: I wonder what error(s) is(are) occured. Error output should be attached into the question to find out better.

Comment: So.. what isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, my bad ! Thing is, my aim is to scrape a PDF file but the download is conditionned by a login, so when I test it, my code redirects me to the login page, consequently the authetification (the filling of the form) didnt't work

There my second part of the code (works with links which does't requires a login):

@watan = {}
 page.parser.xpath('//th/a').each do |link|
  puts @watan[link.text.strip] = link['href']
 end


Thank you!

Comment: Rather than supply the full form, you should truncate it to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem you're having. As is, there's a lot of wasted space from tags that do nothing to explain what you're trying to do and anything more than the bare minimum and you slow down (and discourage) people from trying to help you. For your own testing, reduce it to one or two fields and test against that. Once you can do those, add other types of inputs and form elements. Keep adding until you can handle everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
page = agent.get("your_page_url")

form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_login"
form.password = "my_password"
form.submit
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helps ! unfortunately it's not working; since the first part (authentification) is fine, and the second is fine too (the scraping part, already tested) I'm suspecting a coockies issue; already tried with "temp_jar = agent.cookie_jar.jar" but doesn't work.. any hint ? much appreciated !

Comment: What's not working? You said both the authentication and the scraping are fine.

Comment: separately both codes work, but when I put them together and debug, it seems that they are not linked because the second part (scraping) redirects me to the login page; that's why I guesses that it is a coockies issue. thanks !